# keyboard and mouse dead on wakeup from hibernation - Debian 12

Tags: debian, hibernate

When I resume from suspend everything is fine, however when I resume from hibernation both my mouse and my keyboard are dead.  Very dead -- my keyboard light up when it's on, but after hibernation it's dark, so it's as if the device is simply not powered up. The screens are fine, everything that should be there is there. Still with Debian 11 I never got hibernation to work at all, so we're moving in the right direction.

How can I get my keyboard and mouse working when resuming from hibernation?

Comment: what is your specific question? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

Comment: I've seen regressions in the kernel related to your issue. Please give kernel 6.8 a try.

Comment: Yikes, kernel now is 6.1.  Dare I move up so many notches?  Where would I grab that kernel?

Answer (score 1):

```
in /etc/rc.local:

echo 'on' > /sys/bus/usb/devices/5-2/power/control
echo 'on' > /sys/bus/usb/devices/8-1/power/control
```

... does the trick. Those being the right ports for my devices of course.  To find the right ports:

https://www.makeuseof.com/wake-your-linux-pc-from-suspend-using-usb-devices/